# How to declare a table not-important when using PostgreSQL serializable transactions?

Tags: php, postgresql, serialization, transactions

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 with serializable transactions (similar to predicate locking) and I'm hitting error `could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions`. I believe that this is caused by access to a table that contains data that wouldn't need to be protected by serializable transaction. However, the rest of the code logic depends on serializable transaction support so I need to use serializable transaction for the rest of the tables.

**Is it possible to configure PosgreSQL, database schema or transaction so that I can start a serializable transaction and still declare that any serialization failure in table XYZ is not worth aborting (rollback) the transaction?** If so, how to do it?

The only solution to the problem I'm aware of is to put all not-important tables in an another database and use paraller connection and transaction to that database. I'm hoping for a simpler solution. My application is written in PHP in case that makes a difference.

**Update**: I'm looking for extra *performance*; the code automatically retries the failed transaction and after many enough retries it will eventually go through so in theory I'm good. In practice, the performance sucks a lot.

Comment: Do you have lock-escalation ? Do you encounter plans with seqscans on the "read-only" table(s) ? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html BTW: lowering the number of concurrent sessions is always a good idea ...

Comment: Showing sample code is problematic because the cases where I hit this problem is cases where I do 10-50 queries per transaction in many concurrent transactions and the problematic transaction has around 1000-10000 queries. Each query is pretty simple but somehow PostgreSQL interprets that these transactions have dependencies (I'm guessing some sequential scan is triggered because that is considered as dependency by PostgreSQL).

Comment: Any pointers for debugging unknown dependency sources using PostgreSQL log or other tools would be nice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't allow you to specify this sort of thing.  You should, if this is the case, not use serializable transaction level at all but use more explicit locking (select ... for update, etc).  This may cause deadlocks but avoids the problems you are having now.  You could simulate this by going to read committed and locking relevant rows early on in the transaction.

I am not quite sure to what extent you can use exception handling in user defined functions to get around this issue.  I think it should be possible since functions are at least in theory able to handle all their own exceptions.  However I would worry about implications in messing with transactional guarantees.

Comment: Explicit locking is worse than the current situation because the long running transaction would block all the paraller fast transactions (one cannot free a lock within the transaction so any lock taken will last until the end of transaction). I'm currently automatically retrying the huge transaction until it succeeds, but sometimes it takes really long time (tens of repeats for a set of around 10K queries some take). The problem is *performance*, not the correctness.